# How to fade a .wav file in Java?

Tags: java, audio, fadein, fade, fadeout

Hey I wrote a program which cuts a specific area from a wav file.
But I realized that the cut is very hard so I wanted to fade it in and out. My problem is that I have no idea how to achieve that in java because I'm very new to the sound library from java.

Could someone give a hint or a tip how to achieve that or tip for a resource where I can find the answer?

Here is some code I wrote before:

```
AudioInputStream in = null;
AudioInputStream out = null;

    File originalFile = new File(filePath);
    if (originalFile.exists() && originalFile.isFile())
        {
        File editedFile = new File(newPath);            
        try
            {
            in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(originalFile);
            AudioFileFormat fileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(originalFile);
            AudioFormat format = fileFormat.getFormat();

            int bytesPerSecond = format.getFrameSize() * (int) format.getFrameRate();
            in.skip(start * bytesPerSecond);
            long framesOfAudioToCopy = trackDuration * (int) format.getFrameRate();

            // out is the audiostream which contains the output wav file
            out = new AudioInputStream(in, format, framesOfAudioToCopy);

            // so I guess here would be the right place to fade the audio file
            // just before writing it to the disk

            AudioSystem.write(out, fileFormat.getType(), editedFile);

            System.out.println("Trimming done!");
            System.out.println();
            }
        catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e)
            {
            errorMessage = e.getMessage();
            }
        catch (IOException e)
            {
            errorMessage = e.getMessage();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the controls provided in javax.sound.sampled, [a tutorial is here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/controls.html), but I've never had much luck with them. My experience is that if they exist for a given system (pc/os dependent) there are still issues as the volume changes only occur at buffer boundaries.

Note that the very last part of the tutorial suggests manipulating the audio directly. To do this requires multiple steps.

1) get a hold of the individual bytes of the sound file

There is a code example of this in the very next tutorial on [Using Files and Format Converters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html), the section "reading sound files". In this code example, note the point where we have a comment marking the point where access to the individual bytes has been provided:

```
// Here, do something useful with the audio data that's 
// now in the audioBytes array...
```

2) Convert bytes to PCM (depends on the audio format)

3) multiply by a volume factor

4) increment or decrement the factor (if fading)

5) convert the PCM back to bytes

6) pack and ship via a SourceDataLine (again depends on audio format)

All the steps have been described before in greater detail in StackOverflow and should be searchable, though I don't know how easy it will be at this point to find them.

There are a couple free libraries that will allow real-time volume fading. I wrote [AudioCue](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue) for this (and real time frequency and panning) and there is also [TinySound](https://github.com/finnkuusisto/TinySound).

PS I am happy to answer questions and take suggestions for improvements in presentation for the library I wrote.